# JQuery Toggle Drag, Drop & Contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/gCsih
http://jsfiddle.net/ba5Ld/3/

I'm working on a basic experimental html designer (all you do is draw divs/rectangles and resize them nothing to fancy)

I'm using ThreeDubMedia's drag plugin to accomplish the the drag and resize events.

I know using global variables is bad practice, but I couldn't figureout how to accomplish this type of effect without them.

Anyway I ran into two problems: first is divs are still draggable when select tool is inactive (which moveable is set to false in which I assume it shouldn't be dragging), two when I pick the edit tool when the mouse is down on a div it sets the contenteditable property to true, however it's not working. When I took a look in the google developer tools it shows that the property is added and active but it's not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    $('.start').click(function() {
      moveable = 1;
      drawable = false;
      editable = false;
      removeable = false;
      $('.draw, .nodraw').removeClass('d-active e-active noselect active inactive r-active');
      $(this).addClass('active noselect s-active');
      if ($('.s-active').is(':visible')) {
        if(moveable) {
          $('#drawingArea *').addClass('moveable');

          $('.moveable').drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
            dd.attr = $( ev.target ).prop("className");
            dd.width = $( this ).width();
            dd.height = $( this ).height();
          })
          .drag(function( ev, dd ){
            var props = {};
            if ( dd.attr.indexOf("E") > -1 ){
              props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width + dd.deltaX );
            }
            if ( dd.attr.indexOf("S") > -1 ){
              props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height + dd.deltaY );
            }
            if ( dd.attr.indexOf("W") > -1 ){
              props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width - dd.deltaX );
              props.left = dd.originalX + dd.width - props.width;
            }
            if ( dd.attr.indexOf("N") > -1 ){
              props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height - dd.deltaY );
              props.top = dd.originalY + dd.height - props.height;
            }
            if ( dd.attr.indexOf("editable") > -1 ){
              props.top = dd.offsetY;
              props.left = dd.offsetX;
            }
            $( this ).css( props );
          }, {relative:true});

          $('#drawingArea *').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
            if(moveable) {
              $('#drawingArea *').removeClass('editable');
              $('.handle, .NN, .NE, .EE, .SE, .SS, .SW, .WW, .NW').remove();
              $(this).addClass('editable').append('<div class="handle NE"></div> <div class="handle NN"></div> <div class="handle NW"></div> <div class="handle WW"></div> <div class="handle EE"></div> <div class="handle SW"></div> <div class="handle SS"></div> <div class="handle SE"></div>');
              $('#drawingArea').on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        moveable = false;
        $('.handle, .NN, .NE, .EE, .SE, .SS, .SW, .WW, .NW').remove();
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures are created to do this for you:

```
var a = 1;
(function(){ // Function call creates new scope every time.
    var a = 2;
    // JS look up current scope, then parent to search correct `a` variable
    a = a + 1;
    console.log(a) // -> 3. 
})();

console.log(a) //-> 1, use local scope
```

One more example

```js
var b = 1;
(function(){       // Function call nests new scope
    console.log(b) // -> 1. Use 'b' from parent scope
    b++;           // -> 2. Increase `b` from parent scope
    var b = 1;     // -> 1. Define b in local scope
    console.log(b) // -> 1. This `b` from local scope
})();

console.log(b)     // -> 2. Search in local scope only
```

Each function searching for local scope then parent and so on. Now you can wrap all of your `HTMLNodes` into closures. Example:

```js
$('.start') // -> two or more nodes
    .each(function(i, node){
        // Bind variables in function scope
        var moveable, drawable, editable, removable; 
        $(node).click(function(){
            // If you click twice you will get 'undefined' and 1 respectively.
            console.log(moveable);
            moveable = 1;
            // Do all other useful stuff
        });
```

It is the only answer to your question. But it is not the best or event approperiate solution (you can use jQuery's `data` method to save state of each node). Let me explain. `String` and `Array` are globals, so global variables aren't bad. It's bad practice to use them  to save the *states*.

Comment: Thank you. I apologise for the late reply been working a lot past few weeks. I'll work on utilizing this concept later today, and let you know how it goes.